# Как считать данные с консоли linux которые выводит сторонняя программа

Tags: linux, c

вызываю команду `system ("candump -T 20 can0");` и мне выводятся все принятые  сообщения (по CAN-y) за 20 милисек, в консоль, от программы minicom. Своей программой я хочу "считать" принятые сообщения.

НО как считать сообщения с консоли ??

Я как то понимаю что надо реализовать свои потоки ввода/вывода: возможно кольцевой буфер.

Есть ли уже готовая реализация , можно пожалуйста ссылку где реализовали примерный результат. В верном ли я направлении "копаю" ??

Comment: [C: Run a System Command and Get Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646254)

Comment: Не надо пользоваться `system()`.

Comment: @mkkik пример выводит только то что находиться в папке /etc/  . И не выводит принятые сообщения от команды system

Comment: @0andriy по сути верно, по естеству совершенно не понятно как делать с minicom по коду я общаться не смог , утилита ip оказалась для меня не подъёмной

Comment: В примере показано, как использовать `popen` для системного вызова. Команда `system` не нужна вообще.

Comment: @mkkik показана замена действий (cd, ls )  по сути всё . Совершенно не мой вопрос. (п.с. такое чуство что вы не совсем поняли мой вопрос)

Answer (score 2):

```
candump -T 20 can0 | yourprogram
```

А в программе обрабатываешь stdin (может ещё и stderr, если понадобится). Про потоки можно изнакомиться тут [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Стандартные_потоки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: запускаю в баше программу `./program` `system("candump -T 20 can0 | program");` а дальше я даже не понял

Comment: это нужно сделать из шелла, а не из программы. system вообще использовать ненужно. Нужно использовать чтение из stdin в программе для получения потока от внешней программы, которой является candump, а не запихивать его выполнение внутрь.

Comment: А можете подсказать есть ли какая нибудь книжка где всё это досконально и для дураков расписано ? Пожалуйста.

Comment: первая ссылка в гугле чем не подошла?